# android transition betweene inner layouts

Tags: android, animation, layout

I have this layout setup:

RelativeLayout

```
LinearLayout #1 (visible by default)

LinearLayout #2 (invisible by default)
```

What I need is to have an (sliding or fading) animation when I hide Layout#1 and show Layout#2.

How is it possible?

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309511/android-animation-how-to-sliding-in-and-out-a-layout-from-screen/10309899#10309899

Answer (score 0):

[View.startAnimation(Animation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). I think it is exactly what you want. It allows to switch between views with custom animation.